# When I delete records from table it's coming back again once I created new record?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

When I delete my records and create new records by using sequelize in expressJS
I find in the database the deleted records and new records.

I need to delete all records related to quotationId and then create a new record by using sequelize.
I tried many times but I can't reach the solution for that.

```
const Quotation = require('../models/quotation');
const QuotationItem = require('../models/quotation_item');
const Category = require('../models/category');
const Users = require('../models/users');
const Item = require('../models/item');

exports.postEditQuotation = async (req,res,next) => {
    const quotationId = req.body.quotationId;
    const itemsCodes = req.body.code;
    const itemsPicture = req.body.picture;
    const itemsDesc = req.body.desc;
    const itemsUnit = req.body.unit;
    const itemsQty = req.body.quotationQty;
    const itemsTotal = req.body.quotationTotal;
    const quotationDate = req.body.quotationDate;
    const quotationClient = req.body.quotationClient;
    const quotationAttention = req.body.quotationAttention;
    const quotationLocation = req.body.quotationLocation;
    const quotationSubject = req.body.quotationSubject;

    await Quotation.findOne({ where: { id: quotationId } }).then(quotation => {
        quotation.date = quotationDate;
        quotation.client = quotationClient;
        quotation.attention = quotationAttention;
        quotation.location = quotationLocation;
        quotation.subject = quotationSubject;
        quotation.save();
    }).then(async () => {
        await QuotationItem.destroy({
            where: {
                id: quotationId
            }
        }).then(async () => {
            if(Array.isArray(itemsCodes)) {
                for(let i=0; i< itemsCodes.length; i++){
                    await QuotationItem.create({
                        code : itemsCodes[i],
                        picture : itemsPicture[i],
                        desc : itemsDesc[i],
                        unit : itemsUnit[i],
                        qty : itemsQty[i],
                        total : itemsTotal[i],
                        quotationId : quotationId
                    })
                }
            } else {
                await QuotationItem.create({
                    code : itemsCodes,
                    picture : itemsPicture,
                    desc : itemsDesc,
                    unit : itemsUnit,
                    qty : itemsQty,
                    total : itemsTotal,
                    quotationId : quotationId
                })
            }

        })
    }).then(() => {
        res.redirect('/quotations');
    }).catch(err => {
        const error = new Error(err);
        error.httpStatusCode = 500;
        return next(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: What I see in your code is a broken Promise chain. It means callbacks are sent to `then` functions should return a promise. It simply does not `await` nor your functions run in the  written order.

Comment: Could you explain it by code please, I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is about the broken promise chain. I rewrote your code to address the issue. Please let me know if it solves the main problem.

```js
const Quotation = require('../models/quotation');
const QuotationItem = require('../models/quotation_item');
const Category = require('../models/category');
const Users = require('../models/users');
const Item = require('../models/item');

exports.postEditQuotation = async (req, res, next) => {
  const quotationId = req.body.quotationId;
  const itemsCodes = req.body.code;
  const itemsPicture = req.body.picture;
  const itemsDesc = req.body.desc;
  const itemsUnit = req.body.unit;
  const itemsQty = req.body.quotationQty;
  const itemsTotal = req.body.quotationTotal;
  const quotationDate = req.body.quotationDate;
  const quotationClient = req.body.quotationClient;
  const quotationAttention = req.body.quotationAttention;
  const quotationLocation = req.body.quotationLocation;
  const quotationSubject = req.body.quotationSubject;

  try {
    const quotation = await Quotation.findOne({where: {id: quotationId}})
    quotation.date = quotationDate;
    quotation.client = quotationClient;
    quotation.attention = quotationAttention;
    quotation.location = quotationLocation;
    quotation.subject = quotationSubject;
    await quotation.save();

    await QuotationItem.destroy({
      where: {
        id: quotationId,
      },
      // truncate: true, // <-- try this if you wish
    });

    if (Array.isArray(itemsCodes)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < itemsCodes.length; i++) {
        await QuotationItem.create({
          code: itemsCodes[i],
          picture: itemsPicture[i],
          desc: itemsDesc[i],
          unit: itemsUnit[i],
          qty: itemsQty[i],
          total: itemsTotal[i],
          quotationId: quotationId,
        })
      }
    } else {
      await QuotationItem.create({
        code: itemsCodes,
        picture: itemsPicture,
        desc: itemsDesc,
        unit: itemsUnit,
        qty: itemsQty,
        total: itemsTotal,
        quotationId: quotationId,
      })
    }
    res.redirect('/quotations');
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new Error(err);
    error.httpStatusCode = 500;
    return next(error);
  }
}
```